# eclipse product launching with manual export but not with tycho build no application id has been found dependency leaf issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, tycho

I am trying to automate the build of an rcp application I have it working fine when I create my export an eclipse product however when I generate my rcp application using maven with the tycho plugin it fails to launch when I go to the target and double click the launcher

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <environments>
            <environment>
              <os>win32</os>
              <ws>win32</ws>
              <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </environment>
          </environments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

however when I do a mvn install my package is installed I have my launcher however it fails with the following error log in the config:

```
!SESSION 2013-09-01 16:30:34.345 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IE
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.484
!MESSAGE Product com.hallahan.premierplugin.premierProduct could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.smil 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.smil 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.events_[3.0.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui_3.104.0.v20121024-145224.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.562
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle com.hallahan.premierplugin_1.0.0.201309011530 [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.hallahan.premierplugin 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.batik.css_1.6.0.v201011041432 [6] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.batik.css 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.w3c.dom.svg_[1.1.0,1.3.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.v20120912-132817 [24] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.batik.css_[1.6.0,1.7.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.10.3.v20130123-162658 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.4.v20130123-162658 [26] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_0.10.3.v20130124-185622 [32] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.10.3.v20130124-170312 [33] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.3.v20130124-133900 [34] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.batik.css.engine_1.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui_3.104.0.v20121024-145224 [55] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench_[3.103.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.104.0.v20130204-164612 [56] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_0.10.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627 [58] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.smil 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.events_[3.0.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.smil 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Bundle org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433 [59] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.w3c.dom.smil_[1.0.0,1.1.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-09-01 16:30:35.608
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

There appears to be some problem with the dependency of my plugin

```
osgi> diag 1
initial@reference:file:plugins/com.hallahan.premierplugin_1.0.0.201309021643.jar
 [1]
  Direct constraints which are unresolved:
    Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_0.0.0.
  Leaf constraints in the dependency chain which are unresolved:
    initial@reference:file:plugins/org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar [62]

      Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.events_[3.0.0,4.0.0).
    initial@reference:file:plugins/org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar [62]

      Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi
.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundati
on)(version=1.0)))".
    initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui_3.104.0.v20121024-145224.jar [
59]
      Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi
.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
    initial@reference:file:plugins/org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar [63]
      Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi
.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundati
on)(version=1.0)))".
osgi>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this sorted I identified that there was a discrepancy between the plugins of the manually exported plugins in eclipse against the plugins that were being downloaded from the Juno repository using the maven tycho download.

The org.w3c.dom.smil version 1.0.1 was being downloaded which had a missing dependency. While the manual export which was using the running platform target platform(Kerpler) was version 1.0.0.

I discovered this by doing a diff on the plugins directory of both files.

To get around this I created a tycho target platform file and used this as my target for my build instead of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing exactly the same issue, except that I was trying to run the product through webstart. The PDE export wizard used org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.0.v200806040011.jar but Tycho's target platform (repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler) somehow used org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar instead which gave me a similar error message.

Weird thing is that my Tycho product could still be launched through the .exe.

EDIT: I think I know the cause. My product is based on features and includes org.w3c.dom.smil (0.0.0) which means: use latest available version in the repository. I guess Tycho found a newer version, but it does not automatically include transitive dependencies. It's probably a good idea to configure Eclipse to use exactly the same target platform as Tycho, I think I would have found the issue sooner.